# Why did the index of the for loop change inappropriately?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, indexing

Could anyone tell me why the index of loop is 1 whereas it is initialized as 2 in the `for` loop?

```py
for i in range(0, len(input)):
    if input[i] == 'A':
        if input[i + 1] == 'B':
            flag1 = True
            if i + 2 < len(input):
                i = i + 2
```

After the first loop, `i` changes to 1, but in the loop it is 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `i` is controlled by `range(0, len(input))`. You can modify `i` inside the loop, but on the next iteration it will be reset to the next value in the `range`.

To have complete control over `i`, use a `while` loop:

```
i = 0
while i < len(input):
   # body
   i += 1
```